# Can a charcoal generating process be a low carbon footprint incinerator?

Tags: hydrocarbons, carbon-family, carbon-dioxide

Noting that cellulose, hydrocarbons and carbohydrates are mostly C, H and O, it occurred to me that one might take low grade recyclables no longer welcome, and trash in general, and convert them to energy and carbon using a sophisticated incinerator that uses advanced sensors and computer monitoring, air and heating controls to burn the waste with little carbon footprint.

Heat generated could be recycled to start future  batches, and excess heat could drive power generation.

An interesting side discussion would be how to use the carbon without releasing it to the atmosphere.  Carbon fiber, filtration?

Another aspect is what sorts of other pollution is a problem, like sulfur compounds, carbon monoxide?

Comment: Yes, very simply. Add water and leave it in a pressure reactor vessel for some days. Zero sophistication, just watch the pressure and harvest the produced heat. I'm trying to remember the name of that process. The end result is solid carbon, i.e. charcoal.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrothermal_carbonization 12h, 180°C, 10 bars, gives basically 90% conversion of the contained C to charcoal.

Comment: The trouble are those 180°C. That's basically waste heat, you cannot efficiently run a machine with that, e.g. a generator. My idea would be a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_updraft_tower that uses it as a night heat source, used for desalination and pumping, to water the agriculture/wood farming that produces the biomass.

Comment: Nice, I did not know about its high conversion efficiency and it was discovered in 1913! The only issue is that maintaining 180 C for 12 h. How to achieve this in a green "way"?

Comment: @M.Farooq The process *produces* a lot of heat. Once you have one reactor running, it can start five more. With biomass, microbial decay would start it automatically, but that takes a little more time.

Comment: When the process was "rediscovered" a few years ago I heard a talk by Antonietti about it, and my thought was that the whole thing is embarrassingly obvious. Any undergrad student should come up with charcoal if you asked him what happens if you keep some "sugar" with water at high temperature and pressure. ;-)

Comment: I guess the original experiment is done in a closed system, so you are basically in a steam bath at 180 C.

Comment: @M.Farooq Yea, it's always a closed system. Batch processing, which makes it not very economic.

Comment: Of course, converting these compounds to H2O and C will be net exothermic and so could drive a power producing process like a Stirling Cycle engine or IR solar cell.

What about other elements in the waste stream?  

Can we get C with little or no CO2 or CO?

Is anyone currently incinerating with such a process?

Comment: Batch processing is not prohibited, or completely required, but you might need to process waste to ensure it flows through a streaming process without obstruction.  The most efficient pressure boundary is some sort of pump/turbine, for instance, but a restrictive orifice can hold back pressure and pass small chunks.  We're talking a long insulated stainless steel pipe for the process to complete during a slow flow.

Comment: Stirling engine, OK, a tried and true last resort engine, but *IR solar cells*? Have you got a reputable source for that? You get zero CO, the equillibrium is totally on the side of CO2, but you cannot get rid of the latter, see my answer below.

Comment: While a Stirling cycle engine can harness large amounts of low temp energy, it has moving parts.  While we know radiation energy drops with frequency and IR is below visible frequencies, it has no moving parts.  No excuse for intellectual laziness in the Google age: https://www.google.com/search?q=radiant+infrared+power+generating+cells  Last resort?  That sort of thinking gave us centralized coal and oil fired high temp power plants, huge power grids.  Prioritize by appropriateness and effectiveness, please.

Answer (score 1):

If kept at 200°C with water under pressure, any organic molecules break down after a while, that's called hydrothermal carbonisation, basically how coal was formed geologically

With pure sugar (e.g. cellulose), the gross reaction is

$\ce{4CHO -> 3C + CO2 + 2H2O }$.

Lignin is approximately $\ce{C31H34O11}$ (varies a lot of course, but much lower in oxygen than sugar), so ideally

$\ce{C31H34O11 -> 31C + 6H2 + 11 H2O + 0 CO2}$

or

$\ce{C31H34O11 -> 28C + 3CH4 + 11 H2O + 0 CO2}$,

or other hydrocarbons, depending on the exact conditions.

You can also throw in finely shredded plastic, works the same.

The process obviously produces heat, and some $\ce{CO2}$, because once formed, it only very slowly reacts with hydrocarbon to carbon and water (you need higher temperatures and a potent catalyst for that).

Sulfur containing products can be handled by the same processes as in regular coal power plants, burn and wash out and turn into elementar sulfur.

Comment: I guess you need to introduce some oxygen to combine with the excess H but not so much it reacts with the carbon or other elements?

Comment: One applications would be on a vessel to convert ocean plastics into energy and carbon, which carbon can be discarded to sink, gravity speaking, and the ocean is a great cold sink, thermodynamically speaking, for a heat engine.

Comment: Having seen huge piles of un-recycled plastics in the third world and at home, we have a lot of high energy feed stock.  The general trash stream is a larger but lower energy stream, with lots of moisture, metals, other elements that might become toxic compounds and have to be dealt with carefully, responsibly.  Perhaps a galvanic process up front could pull out metals?  Some places pick over trash for recyclables, but some bits, like aluminum foil on materials like paper and plastic, are hard to recycle in current systems.  My town just recycles metal, paper, #1 and #2.

Comment: My nephew the Chem prof. suggest this would be lots of good college chem student projects: Trying this with different plastics and waste, different pressures, temperatures, duration, in batch or as a continuous flow.  Engineering, too, chemical and general.